# Drawing particular curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, charts, tkz-graph

I need to recreate the curves in the first graph in Latex. What's the best way?

[image: Figure 1]

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=blue, draw=none] (0,0) circle (0.02cm) node (FieldCenter) {};
    %\node (fieldcenterlabel) [above=0.08 of FieldCenter]{\tiny Field Center};
    \draw [draw=black, dotted] (0,0) circle (3.0cm) node () {};
    \draw [draw=black, dashed] (0,0) circle (2.0cm) node () {};
    \draw [draw=black, thin] (0,0) circle (1.0cm) node () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

That code creates this graph:
[image]

Comment: is there any particular math relation about the curves or just aesthetical?

Comment: There is but I'm far from formulating them! I'm working on a thesis and the actual relations aren't known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to draw your incoming lines using `arc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=blue, draw=none] (0,0) circle (0.02cm) node (FieldCenter) {};
    %\node (fieldcenterlabel) [above=0.08 of FieldCenter]{\tiny Field Center};
    \draw [draw=orange, dotted] (0,0) circle (3.0cm) node () {};
    \draw [draw=black, dashed] (0,0) circle (2.0cm) node () {};
    \draw [draw=purple, thin] (0,0) circle (1.0cm) node () {};
    \draw [blue,fill=blue] (0,0) circle (0.5mm);
    \draw [o-,orange, thick]       (140:5mm)  node[right,black]{Label 3} arc (150:190:6);
    \draw [{stealth}-,purple,thin] (145:10mm) node[right,black]{Label 2} arc (150:192:8);
    \draw [{stealth}-]             (95:36mm) node[right,black]{Label 1} arc (140:192:10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The picture that you want and your MWE do not agree on the number of circles, but hopefully this is close to what you want.